# Federated learning with Differential Privacy - Bad test performance

Tags: python, privacy, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I've been playing for some time with FL + DP for my thesis.
I am using TFF in case someone is wondering.

I load my data as:

```
train_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(
        client_ids=train_data_paths,
        create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn
    )

test_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(
        client_ids=test_data_paths,
        create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn
    )
```

And I set Q as sampling ratio

```
def get_training_Q(Q):
    size = int(Q*len(train_data.client_ids))
    sampled_clients = np.random.choice(
            train_data.client_ids,
            size=size,
            replace=False)
    
    sampled_train_data = [
            train_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(client)
            for client in sampled_clients
        ]
    
    return sampled_train_data

def get_test_Q(Q):
    size = int(Q*len(test_data.client_ids))
    sampled_clients = np.random.choice(
            test_data.client_ids,
            size=size,
            replace=False)
    
    ids = [_id.split('/')[-3] for _id in sampled_clients]
    print(ids)
    
    sampled_test_data = [
            test_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(client)
            for client in sampled_clients
        ]
    return sampled_test_data
```

Given this I define my DP parameters:

- Noise = 0.5
- Q = 0.015
- n_clients_per_round = int(Q*len(train_data.client_ids))

I define my aggregation factory:

`aggregation_factory = tff.learning.model_update_aggregator.dp_aggregator(noise_multiplier=Noise,clients_per_round=n_clients_per_round)`

And the iterative process:

```
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_tff,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1),
    model_update_aggregation_factory=aggregation_factory,
    use_experimental_simulation_loop=True)


evaluation = tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation(model_tff,use_experimental_simulation_loop=True)
```

My training happens in rounds as follows:

```
train_set = get_training_Q(Q)
test_set = get_test_Q(Q)

state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, train_set)
test_metrics = evaluation(state.model, test_set)
```

The main issue here is that the training metrics looks good and the model learns at a slow but steady rate but **the test metrics are horrendous**. It looks like the model is overfitting while using DP (known to be a regulariser). I am absolutely confused.
[performance plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiqxZ.png)

I've tried several changes in the noise and learning structure so as modifying the internal rounds of training and the batch size.
I started with a model that trains well without DP to later add DP.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

There may be several reasons why you are having bad performance :

- The level of noise you're adding to the model updates is high leading to poor performance. The solution here is to try to reduce noise multiplier and see the effect on the performance.
- Try a higher sampling rate for client selection. Because by introducing a small subset of clients it is possible that you are introducing a bias to the training process (note that increasing `Q` may increase the cost)

I also recommend to take time for debugging the code the poor performance maybe present because of some bugs.